# how to get unlimited range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Brand As String
    Worksheets("1st").Select
    Brand = Range()
```

Hi, I am using VBA coding in microsoft excel 2011 and I am a little stuck with range. Lets say I want to start something in cell c4, I enter in c4 in the range but if I then want it to continue till all the way down the column (unlimited as we don't know how many rows in that column will be filled up), then what is the correct way of writing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown))
```

This will return the range, C4 to C4 and Down.

This will select all contiguous cell from C4 down all the way until the first blank cell.

Now if you Data has a chance that it might have blanks in between non blank cells. Then you can use the following:

```
Range("C4", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

this will select C4 to The last cell in C columns up until the the cell with data. In other words this will select EVERY cell in the C column from C4 until the last cell in the entire column with a value, and include blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
Sub Main()

     Dim Brand As String
     Dim lastRow As Long
     Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1st")

    With sht
     lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If lastRow < 4 Then lastRow = 4

    Set rng = sht.Range("C4:C" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
       MsgBox cell.Value
    Next

End Sub
```